# How do I modify jQuery .each() so that I only get N items, and not all of them?

Tags: jquery, rss

I am using jQuery to parse an XML feed to create a custom RSS Feed.

Here is what I have:

```
        var $XML = $(data);
        $XML.find("item").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                item = {
                    title: $this.find("title").text(),
                    link: $this.find("link").text(),
                    description: $this.find("description").text(),
                    pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                    author: $this.find("author").text()
                };
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<h2/>').text(item.title));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<a/>').text(item.link));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<p/>').text(item.description));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<p/>').text(item.pubDate));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<p/>').text(item.author));
        });
```

My question is, how do I modify this,specifically `.each()`, so that I only get the latest 3 items, and not all of them?

Comment: Are "the latest 3 item" at beginning or end of `$XML`?

Comment: @guest271314 I just figured it out, see my answer

Comment: See [What is a canonical question/answer, and what is their purpose?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose). Is the present Question intended to be a canonical Question/Answer as to how to stop  jQuery `.each()` from continuing to iterate elements if a condition is met or not met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I figured this out by reading [this](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

I modified my existing code to this:

```
<script>
    $.get("https://test.com/feed/", function (data) {
        var $XML = $(data);
        $XML.find("item").each(function (index) {
            var $this = $(this),
                item = {
                    title: $this.find("title").text(),
                    link: $this.find("link").text(),
                    description: $this.find("description").text(),
                    pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                    author: $this.find("author").text(),
                };
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<h2/>').text(item.title));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<a href="' + item.link + '"/>').text(item.link));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<br/>'));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<p/>').text(item.description));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<br/>'));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<p/>').text(item.pubDate));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<br/>'));
            $('#TestFeed').append($('<p/>').text(item.author));

            if (index >= 2)
                return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.